# Updating firestore document nested data overwrites it

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to set some new fields in a nested dict within a Firestore document, which results in the data being overwritten.
Here's where I write the first part of the info I need:

```
upd = {
"idOffer": {
                <offerId> : {
                    "ref" : <ref>,
                    "value" : <value>
                }
            }
}
<documentRef>.update(upd)
```

So output here is something like:

```
<documentid>:{idOffer:{<offerId>:{ref:<ref>, value:<value>}}}
```

Then I use this code to add some fields to the current `<offerId>` nested data:

```
approval = {
            "isApproved" : <bool>,
            "dateApproved" : <date>,
            "fullApproval" : <bool>
        }
<documentRef>.update({
            "idOffer.<offerId>" : approval
        })
```

From which I expect to get:

```
<documentid>:{idOffer:{<offerId>:{ref:<ref>, value:<value>, isApproved:<bool>,dateApproved:<date>,fullApproval:<bool>}}}
```

But I end up with:

```
<documentid>:{idOffer:{<offerId>:{isApproved:<bool>,dateApproved:<date>,fullApproval:<bool>}}}
```

Note: I use <> to refer to dynamic data, like document Ids or References.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call update with a dictionary (or map, or object, or whatever key/value pair structure used in other languages), the entire set of data behind the given top-level keys are going to be replaced.  So, if you call update with a key of `idOffer.<offerId>`, then everything under that key is going to be replaced, while every *other* child key of the `idOffer` level will remain unchanged.

If you don't want to replace the entire object behind the key, then be more specific about which children you'd like to update.  In your example, instead of updating a single `idOffer.<offerId>` key, specify three keys for the nested children:

- `idOffer.<offerId>.isApproved`
- `idOffer.<offerId>.dateApproved`
- `idOffer.<offerId>.fullApproval`

That is to say, the dictionary you pass should have three keyed entries like this at the top level, rather than a single key of `idOffer.<offerId>`.